# What is the meaning of a "*" before a string in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to understand this algorithm, which reverses a C-style character in-place. I don't understand what the `*` indicates in the context of being before a string and in the context of "char * end." Thanks for your help!

```
void reverse(char *str) {
    char * end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str) {
        while (*end) {
        ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (str < end) {
            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a pointer to a type of `char`...been a while, but it would appear to be doing some pointer arithmetic, walking between sequential memory locations

Comment: is that tag [java] correct?

Comment: That will not compile in Java.

Comment: That is **not** Java. That is good old `C`

Comment: I don't see any *'s before strings.

Comment: Thanks---I'm brushing up on my Java, and I just could not remember ever seeing these asterisks. Well, there's that question answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk refers to a `pointer`

```
char tmp
```

This is a character

```
char * str
```

This is a pointer to a char (or char array in this case).

```
tmp = *str;
```

Means that the character `tmp` is filled with the first character from the string array pointed to by the pointer `str`.

Comment: `this is a pointer to a char array.` No, it's a pointer to a character. That character may or may not be the first character in a character array.

Answer (score 0):

You are really interested in learning then you need to learn basic of c first then pointer:

This one is a very quick tutorial of pointers : http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers then go through this and see string as pointer : https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/string/intro/

I will suggest to go through them once help you in understanding many things in other languages also. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a character pointer when you use a "*" before a string..
This is also treated as character array where the string entered after"*" will be the name of that array.